# How to position a text field, under another with variable height

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a dynamic text field that fills with different amounts of text each day. So, the height varies. And I would like to position a 2nd text field below it, with a 50px margin. The second text field would move up and down in relationship to the first.

How would I go about that? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textfield2.y = textfield1.y + textfield1.height + 50;
```

This should do it unless I'm misunderstanding your question.